# Effect of MSO/MSE split on consecutive day counts

Tags: support, mso-mse-split

It appears that consecutive day counts are tracked separately between main sites and their corresponding meta site. How will the MSO/MSE split affect the consecutive day count on Meta Stack Overflow? That is, will we...

- Carry the MSO count to the new MSE profile (so my 77 days on MSO become 77 days on MSE),
- Keep the MSO count on the MSO profile (even though the meta site will be brand-new), or
- Exhibit a different behavior?

Comment: Will the new MSO site even *have* accounts when it is created though? From what I understood, everything is just being moved to MSE. So you would create a new account on MSO by visiting for the first time, which would get connected to your main SO account. I doubt accounts would be pre-populated.

Comment: This comment, it's user, it's user's data, and all it's user's posts are on the MSO DB, which will be renamed to the MSE DB, and that's it.

Comment: Oh gods, what if badges aren't migrated, and the awarding scripts run...

Comment: And this matters excactly ... how?

Comment: All consecutive day counts are reset to 0 on both sites, and everyone loses their badges. It's the only fair way. <3

Comment: I actually kinda want that to happen, @Kevin.

Comment: @davidkonrad It *does* affect the behaviour of some badges.

Comment: Now I get it, the "fanatic" badge and so on. Well, then start over. I did that. I was on 98 once, but then I had to go to Christmas with my family :) It is not catastrophic. You will get another chance, I would say.

Comment: @davidkonrad - Yeah, I think I had gotten into the 80s once on Stack Overflow and lost it (I did reach Fanatic later though). It's not the hugest thing, but I was just curious. Thanks all for the comments!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Carry the MSO count to the new MSE profile (so my 77 days on MSO become 77 days on MSE)

That. Your MSE profile will be your current MSO profile, with the existing record of days on which you've been active.

Your MSO profile will be *brand-new*, created the first time you visit the site. You will not have any record of having previously been there, because... in a sense... you haven't.

Comment: Ah, ok! Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: "because... in a sense... you haven't" - dun dun dunnnnn (Directed by M. Night Shyamalan)