# How can I have a Yearling badge on the new meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, meta, yearling-badge

My badges and rep from the previous meta.stackoverflow have been moved to meta.stackexchange (here). The new meta.stackoverflow inherits my rep from stackoverflow.

So why do I have exactly one badge, Yearling, on meta.stackoverflow? And how can I have a Yearling badge on a site which is effectively only a few hours old?

Comment: I even have the [Fanatic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/fanatic?userid=212576) badge :)

Comment: Related on per-site meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250014/why-are-we-getting-yearling-badges-for-a-site-that-is-1-day-old

Comment: Er... So does this mean I have asked this on the wrong site? I'm confused already...

Comment: @Wikis No, this is the right place. He was just sharing a related question on another Meta. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child meta profiles just stay in sync with the parent meta profile on the site, which means MSO will *act* as if it just always existed since Stack Overflow did. It's a bit strange because almost 5 years worth of badges got granted mostly at once, but it's by design.

Answer (score 2):

The Yearling badge has always been awarded whenever your account reaches another multiple  of `1 year account age + 200 reputation`, regardless of the time period over which the change actually occurred. Your Meta Stack Overflow account inherits both age and reputation from your main Stack Overflow account, so when the yearling badge task is run it will award as many badges to your new meta account as were earned by your primary account.

Comment: This might shed more light on things: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229735/212576